# How to apply multiple cropped blurs?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to apply multiple blurs into my video (with audio copied), each of them having different coordinates and durations. Here is what I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=w=100:h=100:x=20:y=40,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,5,8)'[c1];
[0:v]crop=w=100:h=100:x=40:y=60,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,10,13)'[c2];
[0:v][c1]overlay=x=20:y=40[v];
[0:v][c2]overlay=x=40:y=60[v]" \
-map "[v]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

However, this results in a `Filter overlay has an unconnected output` error. I would like to know if there is any good way to solve this. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd overlay should use the output of the first overlay as its base input.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=w=100:h=100:x=20:y=40,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,5,8)'[c1];
[0:v]crop=w=100:h=100:x=40:y=60,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,10,13)'[c2];
[0:v][c1]overlay=x=20:y=40:enable='between(t,5,8)'[v0];
[v0][c2]overlay=x=40:y=60:enable='between(t,10,13)'[v]" \
-map "[v]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I've tried it and it didn't cause any errors. However, the blurred area seems to be "cropped", maybe because the crop areas are overlapping to each other.

Comment: adding `enable=between()` section to the overlay filters (corresponding to the boxblur filters) solved the overlapping crop problem! Thanks @Gyan you saved my day